# Qhull(Qhalf) interior point

Tags: convex-hull, qhull

I am using qhull library for for computing the intersection of half spaces. Although this problem is a dual of convex hull problem, but as its input it needs an interior point of the intersection. As it is stated on their webpage, [here](http://www.qhull.org/html/qhalf.htm#notes), using linear programming we can find such a point. However, even for simple 2D cases, this LP problem does not have a bounded solution. Is there something wrong with the given instruction on the qhull website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer myself! Yest the LP would be unbounded and we need to set an upper bound, depending on the context of the given problem.